# Holotoolkit. Where are the Test Assets

Tags: toolkit, hololens

In the [Holotoolkit getting started](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/master/GettingStarted.md) Step #3 it talks about adding the package to your project. It says in the last line in italics
*Note: This process should be repeated for the examples and test asset packages as well.*

Well, in the downloads for the toolkit there are examples and "Preview Features" but not Test asset packages.

Where are they? Are these not necessary anymore?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

So when adding Holotoolkit to a Unity project - just drag the following into your project.  You can do likewise with the "Holotoolkit-Examples" as well.  All the assets you'll need are under those folders.  Regards. :)